# sts tool i used <parent> getting error in pom

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin, parent-pom

I tried to create a new spring starter project, in the pom.xml file I'm getting an error with `<parent>` tag

I have copied my pom file below.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.5.10.RELEASE
    
    com.example
    springboot-mongodb-example
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    springboot-mongodb-example
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Why I'm getting the error. without nothing, I did in code just created a new project. please help me come out.thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please update the description with the error details which you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Ganesa, for your comment  ,my issue is resolved by prooxy details in m2 repository i changed the <proxy> details